# How can I save and load from preferences the entries of a listview that has multiple types of entries?

Tags: android

I have a listview that displays a list of interfaces, where the interface is implemented by two types of classes:

1) An entry with a date

2) A header that break up the entries by day

My issue is being able to save and load the list of interfaces into preferences when the app is opened/closed. From what I understand, I need to use an [interface adapter](https://technology.finra.org/code/serialize-deserialize-interfaces-in-java.html) to serialize/deserialize the list of interfaces.

I tried following the tutorial but I'm getting an error

```
 Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

from the line "gson.fromJson(json, type)" in the "loadCLEntries" function below. Below is my relevant code.

Interface:

```
public interface CallLogListViewItem {
    //These are so the list view can tell if an entry is a header or an entry
    public int getViewType();
    public View getView(LayoutInflater inflater, View convertView);
}
```

List being displayed in listview:

```
private static List<CallLogListViewItem> callLogEntries = new ArrayList<>();
```

Code that loads the entries + headers from preferences when app is opened:

```
private static ArrayList<CallLogListViewItem> loadCLEntries() {
    SharedPreferences pref = App.getApp().getSharedPreferences("info", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String json = pref.getString("CallLogEntries", "[]");

    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<CallLogListViewItem>>(){}.getType();

    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(CallLogListViewItem.class, new InterfaceAdapter<>());
    Gson gson = builder.create();

    return gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
```

Code to save the headers + entries when app is closed:

```
private static void saveCLEntries() {
    //Save entries
    SharedPreferences pref = App.getApp().getSharedPreferences("info", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(callLogEntries, CallLogListViewItem.class);
    editor.putString("CallLogEntries", json);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem is that I'm saving the list of interfaces incorrectly.

When serializing the list, I need to also use the interface adapter:

```
private static void saveCLEntries() {
    //Save entries
    SharedPreferences pref = App.getApp().getSharedPreferences("info", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<CallLogListViewItem>>(){}.getType();

    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(CallLogListViewItem.class, new InterfaceAdapter<>());
    Gson gson = builder.create();

    String json = gson.toJson(callLogEntries, type);
    editor.putString("CallLogEntries", json);
    editor.apply();
}
```

And that was it.